# Unable to test functions in password filter DLL with GetProcAddress

Tags: c++, dll

I'm building a password filter as demonstrated with by the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721882(v=vs.85).aspx

I attempted to build a dll and load it on a test machine following the instructions provided by MS and discovered something was obviously wrong as the dll was not getting loaded.  So I then decided to run a unit test program on the dll and that doesn't seem to work either.  Rather, it works if I use mangled functions without use of the extern "C" directive or an .def file.  As soon as I do use extern "C" or the def file, the code doesn't work.

The Code below produces the error code 127: The specified procedure could not be found.  Despite me using extern "C" and using Dependency Walker to get the name of the function, I'm told by the code that the function could not be found.

Here is the unit test app:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <NTSecAPI.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

typedef NTSTATUS (__stdcall *MYPROC)(PUNICODE_STRING, ULONG, PUNICODE_STRING);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MYPROC ProcAdd;
    HMODULE MyDllHnd = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\Users\\mmatovic\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\PasswordFilterUnitTest\\Debug\\PasswordFilter.dll"));
    if (NULL == MyDllHnd)
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        cout << "Error: " << dwError << endl;
    }

    ProcAdd = (MYPROC)GetProcAddress(
        MyDllHnd,
        "PasswordChangeNotify");

    ULONG rid = 0;

    if (NULL != ProcAdd)
    {
        (ProcAdd)((PUNICODE_STRING)"test",(ULONG)0,(PUNICODE_STRING)"test");
    } else {
        DWORD dwProcError = GetLastError();
        cout << "Error: " << dwProcError << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code for the actual DLL:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define LOGFILE "c:\\PasswordFilter.txt"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void WriteToLog (PUNICODE_STRING str)
{
#ifdef LOGFILE
    FILE* log = fopen(LOGFILE, "a");
    if(NULL == log)
    {
        return;
    }
    fprintf(log, "%s\r\n", str);
    fclose(log);
#endif
    return;
}

BOOLEAN __stdcall InitializeChangeNotify(void)
{
    return TRUE;
}

NTSTATUS __stdcall PasswordChangeNotify(
    PUNICODE_STRING UserName,
    ULONG RelativeId,
    PUNICODE_STRING NewPassword
)
{
    WriteToLog(UserName);
    WriteToLog(NewPassword);
    return 0;
}

BOOLEAN __stdcall PasswordFilter(
    PUNICODE_STRING AccountName,
    PUNICODE_STRING FullName,
    PUNICODE_STRING Password,
    BOOLEAN SetOperation
)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

And lastly the contents of the .def file

```
LIBRARY PasswordFilter

EXPORTS
    InitializeChangeNotify
    PasswordChangeNotify
    PasswordFilter
```

Also the stdafx.h file generated in VS for the DLL code:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winnt.h>
#include <NTSecAPI.h>
```

Comment: -1 Please define "doesn't work"

Comment: My apologies.  I got dragged into a meeting as soon as I started this question.  Please note above the actual issues with the unit test code.  I will post the code for the dll as well shortly.

Comment: Please could you remove all the `FormatMessage` code that obscures the problem. Spitting to the console the result of a call to `GetLastError` suffices. If you must call `FormatMessage` then for the love of god don't use copy/paste every time you want to call it. Please add the DLL code.

Comment: You'll have to get rid of all those string type casts, they cannot work.  Converting strings from narrow to wide characters or the other way around requires a conversion, not a cast.

Comment: Yes, the casting is no good. But I really cannot stomach this with all the spurious code. So, good luck, but I don't want to get any deeper with the question as it is now.

Comment: I'm updating the code to incorporate the changes you've requested as to make the code lean and less "spurious".  Hopefully that enables you to help me out.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  Not to anyone's real surprise from this thread, but I solved the issue and it was because I'm a moron :-/

I had pointed to the wrong dll file.  Sorry to waste your time.